# macOS Sierra: Connections to local servers constantly failing

Tags: network-shares, nas, smb, macos-sierra, afp

I'm running CrashPlan on a headless (I manage everything through TeamViewer) Mac mini (Late 2012), essentially just as a relay since the backup source is a local NAS and the destination is a different local NAS - all within the same LAN. The devices are hardwired to each other through Ethernet. The source is mounted as an SMB volume and so do the various destinations (a different NAS, and an external drive connected to the source NAS).

The connections never last more than 24 hours and I have to manually re-mount them every time, and it's a nightmare with CrashPlan because it severely disturbs the normal operation of the backup process.

If this helps, these are the mini's power settings:

- Computer sleep is set to "Never" (Display sleep is set to 1 minute, but I guess it's meaningless)
- "Put hard disks to sleep when possible" is UNTICKED
- "Wake for network access" is TICKED
- "Start up automatically after a power failure" is TICKED "Enable Power Nap" is TICKED

P. S. - I tried to mount the volumes as AFP volumes, same results. I also tried to use [MountWatcher](http://plumamazing.com/mac/mountwatcher/), to no avail either.

What could be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you allow the mini to sleep?

Comment: No... It's set to "Never".

Comment: & you're hardwired to the LAN? If so, I'm stumped, sorry. I've heard of wifi dropping off the line periodically, but never hard-wire. I have Macs here that have literally been on 24/7 for 8 or 9 years & never dropped the connection [unless rebooted etc]

Comment: That is correct, the setup is hard wired. Maybe I'm having these issues because of the NAS itself hibernating?

Comment: One last guess - has this started since Sierra? I've found Sierra to be more trouble than any other Mac OS ever [& my first was System 6.0.6] I've tested every point release since the betas & every time gone back to El Cap.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This might be the reason, but I can't tell for sure since I'm running this setup using Sierra from the beginning. This is worth checking out. How can I revert back to El Capitan? P. S. - Between AFP and SMB, what is your recommendation?

Comment: 'Reverting' to El Cap isn't straightforward, essentially you wipe & start over unless you have a backup from that period. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271104/revert-to-el-capitan for some trials & tribulations on a machine I thought I had backed up to the hilt :/ AFP/SMB I have no real preference. Both are set up, Macs tend to use AFP, Win SMB, but I've never exactly measured/tracked it, tbh.